# Landscape Mode Errors

Tags: android, landscape-portrait

I am developing an Android App. Working on the LandingPage and the SignIn/ SignUp Part. I have some issues with the Landscape Mode.

For the methods setFontType() and addSoundtoButtons() the part referring to the "normal" Buttons is functioning, while the part referring to the "landscape" Buttons is not functioning.

For the Font Method I get the following error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference

For the Sound Method I get the following error message:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Following is the Code:

```
public class LandingPage extends AppCompatActivity {

Button log_in_normal, sign_up_normal, log_in_landscape, sign_up_landscape;
Typeface tfc_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page);

    log_in_normal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button_Normal);
    sign_up_normal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button_Normal);
    log_in_landscape = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button_Landscape);
    sign_up_landscape = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button_Landscape);

    setFontType();
    addSoundtoButtons();

}

public void addSoundtoButtons(){
    //Add Sound to the Buttons
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.button_click_sound);
    log_in_normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    sign_up_normal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    log_in_landscape.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
    sign_up_landscape.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
}

public void setFontType(){

    //Set Font Type for Buttons
    tfc_button = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TEMPSITC.TTF");

    log_in_normal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button_Normal);
    sign_up_normal = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button_Normal);
    log_in_landscape = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button_Landscape);
    sign_up_landscape = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button_Landscape);

    log_in_normal.setTypeface(tfc_button);
    sign_up_normal.setTypeface(tfc_button);
    log_in_landscape.setTypeface(tfc_button);
    sign_up_landscape.setTypeface(tfc_button);
}

public void OnClick(View view){

    if (view.getId() == R.id.LogIn_Button_Normal){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.SignUp_Button_Normal){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.LogIn_Button_Landscape){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else if (view.getId() == R.id.SignUp_Button_Landscape){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpPage.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have two different versions of `activity_landing_page.xml`? One in `res/layout/` and one in `res/layout-land/` ?

Comment: Yes both under one main xml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, imagine you have this layout in your `res/layout/` directory:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogIn_Button_Normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SignUp_Button_Normal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign up"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Additionally, you have this layout in your `res/layout-land/` directory:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/LogIn_Button_Landscape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Log in"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/SignUp_Button_Landscape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign up"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The critical thing to understand is that your activity will only inflate **one of these** (based on your device's orientation), and not both. That means:

- If the device is in portrait mode, `LogIn_Button_Normal` and `SignUp_Button_Normal` will be in the layout
- If the device is in landscape mode, `LogIn_Button_Landscape` and `SignUp_Button_Landscape` will be in the layout
- Whichever orientation your device is in, the **other** buttons won't be in the layout

Normally, the way to handle this is to make sure that your two different layouts use the same `id`s for each element. That is, instead of having `LogIn_Button_Normal` and `LogIn_Button_Landscape`, each of your layouts should just have `LogIn_Button`. That way, whichever of the two layouts is inflated you'll always have a `LogIn_Button` button.

So, change your ids to `LogIn_Button` and `SignUp_Button` in both layouts, and then change your code to:

```
public class LandingPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button log_in, sign_up;
    Typeface tfc_button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page);

        log_in = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LogIn_Button);
        sign_up = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignUp_Button);

        setFontType();
        addSoundtoButtons();
    }

    public void addSoundtoButtons() {
        //Add Sound to the Buttons
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button_click_sound);
        log_in.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
        sign_up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public void setFontType() {

        //Set Font Type for Buttons
        tfc_button = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/TEMPSITC.TTF");

        log_in.setTypeface(tfc_button);
        sign_up.setTypeface(tfc_button);
    }

    public void OnClick(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.LogIn_Button) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (view.getId() == R.id.SignUp_Button) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignUpPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```